# Bookmarklet to change the arbitrary value of a JSON config

Tags: javascript, json, bookmarklet

I'm working on changing the UX of a proprietary, heavily obfuscated and tamper-proof web application, so I can't nip this in the bud at server level; I'm limited to the sandbox of my browser and bookmarklets.

A page loads up main code (`<script preload>`) and user config (`<script defer>`) in two separate queries. I would like for a setting in the user config to have a different value than what the server sends.

Doing it for myself, I could tamper with the config before it even arrives in the browser, but I have to make this work reliably for other users as well, without having them to install a whole bunch of stuff like Greasemonkey, Fiddler, whatever.

I've tried two equally inefficient approaches:

1. When the page starts loading, execute this and hope I win the race:

```
{
   var loadedConf = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML;
   if(typeof loadedConf === "undefined")
   {
      setTimeout(raceReplace, 5);
      rantime += 5;
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = loadedConf.replace(/arbitraryConfigField":false/,
         'arbitraryConfigField":"arbitraryConfigValue"');
      console.log("Raced to a finish in " + rantime + "ms")
   }
}
raceReplace()
```

Because it's a race, it's wholly contingent upon how fast a user clicks the bookmarklet. With practice, I can do it almost 50% of the time! Heh.

2. Extend JSON.parse to make it return an object as it normally would, the way God and Douglas Crockford intended, except an arbitrary key/value:

```
JSON.parse = (text, fn) => {
  const result = parse(text, fn)
  if (result && result.arbitraryConfigField) {
    result.arbiraryConfigField = 'arbitraryConfigValue'
  }
  return result
}
```

A better approach, but also prone to racing and could hinder regular JSON.parse performance.

(I'm wondering if performance-wise it wouldn't be better to just do a text.replace without any checking.)

Is there yet a third way to wait for the page to load, hook into it and on a subsequent reload (which, yes, necessarily re-renders everything) have the necessary value without the hassle and uncertainty of a race?

It would be grear to have this without the heavy artillery of designing a Chrome extension or hooking with Greasemonkey.

Comment: You could have this running in just a few minutes in a userscript manager like Tampermonkey without the race to initialize in time. A reload doesn't help since each page load removes prior loaded script, even your bookmark code

Comment: Re-reading my formulated problem, I realize this as well, yeah. I was hoping for a sort of way to reload the page softly, retaining the context…

Comment: Pages are stateless...new window...new code. Other than using browser storage for some data you can retrieve with js, nothing is left behind from prior window.....the old tenant has cleaned up and is gone!.